# How to not exit out of method after switch C#

Tags: c#, methods, switch-statement

So I am wondering how to make a method that has a switch statement in it not close after a case is done. Here is what I've done.

```
public static int Store(int cashyo)
    {
        int open = 1;

        while (open != 0)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to buy?");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            string option = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (option)
            {
                case "bye":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Leaving store.");
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    open = 0;
                    break;

                case "list":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Bike");
                    break;

                case "bike":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    if (cashyo >= 300)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Purchased Bike for 300 USD!");
                        return (cashyo-3000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Canot purchase Bike. Insufficient amount of funds.");
                        return cashyo;
                    }
                    break;

            }
            return cashyo;
        }
        return cashyo;
    }
```

cashyo is a dummy variable for the actual money used in main. I want to make it so that if I type "bike" it purchases the bike and then asks me what I want to do again, since open still isn't 0.

Comment: Do you know what the `return` keyword does?

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess not, been coding for 6 days now. I am a little slow I know.

Comment: You could put your call to `Store` in a loop until a certain condition is met, like the user says they want to buy nothing, or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the return statement immediately following the switch and remove the 2 returns in your bike section (you'll also want to set the new cashyo value where you subtract). Also noticed that you're checking against 300, but subtracting 3000 in the bike section.

Return means "leave the procedure", so it's not looping back because you're telling it to end.

Comment: Thank you so much.